# Interval in query options and the resulting number changing from resolution to resolution

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I’m quite a beginner of Grafana and Prometheus, I’m facing a strange situation about a stat widget showing a number, the prometheus query is simply this:
sum(my_metric_counter)

I tried to compose a screenshot where you can see steps I do to reproduce what I think is a problem, but I understand that the interval query option work in that way, it considers the resolution of the panel and the time-range, so in this way the interval changes varying the panel size.

Well, but that number, when my users see in dashboard, where it is very small, doesn’t show right number because of its big interval of 15m which cut off some points.

How can I set a static interval or how should I change, if possible, Grafana settings to accomplish my tasks in your opinion?

Thanks in advance, best regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the [series selector](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) into [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) function with some pre-defined lookbehind window in square brackets. For example:

```
sum(last_over_time(my_metric_counter[5m]))
```

In this case the query result shouldn't depend on the interval between points on the graph in Grafana.